# How to compile your python program to windows executable file using linux OS? what compiler should i use?

Tags: python, linux, windows, compiler-errors, pyinstaller

I use Linux OS to make apps on python but want to share my app with my friends who use windows

I used pyinstaller but i found out that it can only compile for linux using linux OS
i program on linux OS and i want to share the app i created with my friend who uses windows OS so is there any compiler that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile it on windows in order to run it on windows.
I don't have 100% working solution, but if you don't have a windows machine to compile your code on, you could try to use some kind of virtual machine or docker and compile your code on it.